# Coerce dataframe groups to list

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe such as

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3)
element <- c(25122,356,4454,5432,342340,12443,12354,123536,234134)
df <- data.frame(id = as.factor(id), element)
```

I would like to create a list of the `id` groups with their corresponding `element`s such as:

```
dflist <- list(c(25122,356,4454), c(5432,342340), c(12443,12354,123536,234134))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `split`

```
unname(split(df$element, df$id))
```

---

Or with `unstack`

```
unname(unstack(df, element ~id))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with tapply:

```
library(magrittr)
df %$% tapply(element,id,list)
```

(elements are named with id, add `%>% unname` if it's an issue)